# background attachment fixed works only in chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make background image not moving on scroll with `background-attachment: fixed`. But this only works in Chrome and IE11. Id does not work in Firefox and Edge. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong because this should be pretty basic thing to work. Also i have tried to put another div inside the `.header-homepage` with `position: fixed` and full width and height but that is also not working in Firefox or edge and it also breaks everything in chrome for some reasons. Same thing for pseudo element on `.header-homepage`.

css

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.header-homepage {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/16/unsplash_5263605581e32_1.JPG");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

html

```
<!--header-->
<header class="header-homepage">

  <!--intro-->
  <div class="header-homepage__intro">
    <h1>
            Text
        </h1>

    <div class="header-homepage__intro__description">
      Text text text
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--end intro-->

</header>
<!--end header-->
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/LxeVbR

Comment: background-attachment:fixed seems to be supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment#Browser_compatibility

Comment: it is, dunno whats going on here

Comment: Seems to be because of `transform-style: preserve-3d;` but I don't know why.